# Is it possible to disable Google Voice Search headset control in 4.1 Jelly Bean?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, headset, google-voice-actions

I flashed my Samsung Galaxy S i9000 with the RemICS-JB 3.0 ROM, and now long-press on my headset is hard-coded to start Google Voice Search, which doesn't interest me. I'd much rather have long-press be available to other apps (I used it as "rewind" in my podcast player). Is it possible to disable this hard-coded headset control, or disable Voice Search entirely? There isn't a separate app for it, and I can't seem to disable the Google Search app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the "headset button controls" available on the playstore, e.g. [JAYS Headset Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=se.jays.headsetcontrol) or [Philips Headset](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.philips.cl.headset). Both allow you to define an app started automatically when your headset attaches, and as well to assign actions on short/long/combined headset button presses.

To make that better understandable, let's take the morse code: `.` is short, `-` is long press. So the default configuration e.g. does on...

- `.` play/pause or answer incoming call
- `-` increase volume
- `.-` decrease volume
- `..` skip to next title or reject incoming call

and more, up to triple combinations. With most of these apps, actions can be freely configured.